# Two opposite onramps one city

Tags: no-computers

Is it possible to have two freeway on-ramps,(one going north and one going south), and have them both go to the same city?

Comment: Perhaps edit this to state explicitely that the on-ramps should both proceed from the same city, and end up at another city (and continue straight in the direction they started, if this was your intention for the question, as it is a bit vague at the moment)

Comment: I think this question is missing a lot of limitations and details to cut out trivial answers. Maybe there is an intelligent riddle behind it, but it needs revision. - And please tag it right, the tag "no-computers" seems completely unrelated... *voted to close as too broad

Comment: Yes. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/M25_motorway

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure. One on-ramp is somewhere north of the city and one is somewhere to the south. There's nothing in the question indicating that the on-ramps have to be in the same place.

Comment: This answer seems logical and correct according to the limitations set in the question. But I think the question asker should rather have been more thorough in setting said limitations, I'm sure he intended it otherwise.

Comment: Good work.......

Answer (score 6):

Suppose if we want to goto City A from City B, then:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Sure. There can be two cities, one at the Eastern edge and one at the Western edge of a loop formed by a freeway that runs in a circle. From the city on the West, the North ramp runs counter-clockwise and the South ramp leads clockwise to the city on the East.

There are several such loops near Houston. For example, from Jersey Village, 8N and 8S both go to Houston. 610 is similar.

Answer (score -3):

The city can be

> Sirsi

Because -

> There is Sirsi in Karnataka , Southern part of India .

Also,

> There is Sirsi in Uttar Pradesh , Northern part of India.

So , if we move north and south we go to same city .

Comment: That's two different cities with the same name, not the same city.